# Show cut categories in R without e formatting

Tags: r

I am cutting a vector using `cut` functionality:

```
num_seq <- 1:2000
break_m <- seq(0, 2000, by=30)
num_broken <- cut(num_seq, breaks = break_m)
unique(num_broken)
```

The problem is that the display of the categories `num_broken` has `e` notation
e.g. `(1.35e+03,1.38e+03]`

I tried the below:

```
as.numeric(num_broken)
```

But this just makes it a series of numbers like:

```
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 1
```

Also tried these, they don't help

```
format(unique(num_broken), digits = 10)
options(scipen=999)
```

How can I get an output like `(1350,1380]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
#Code
num_seq <- 1:2000
break_m <- seq(0, 2000, by=30)
num_broken <- cut(num_seq, breaks = break_m,dig.lab = 10)
unique(num_broken)
```

Outout:

```
 [1] (0,30]      (30,60]     (60,90]     (90,120]    (120,150]   (150,180]   (180,210]  
 [8] (210,240]   (240,270]   (270,300]   (300,330]   (330,360]   (360,390]   (390,420]  
[15] (420,450]   (450,480]   (480,510]   (510,540]   (540,570]   (570,600]   (600,630]  
[22] (630,660]   (660,690]   (690,720]   (720,750]   (750,780]   (780,810]   (810,840]  
[29] (840,870]   (870,900]   (900,930]   (930,960]   (960,990]   (990,1020]  (1020,1050]
[36] (1050,1080] (1080,1110] (1110,1140] (1140,1170] (1170,1200] (1200,1230] (1230,1260]
[43] (1260,1290] (1290,1320] (1320,1350] (1350,1380] (1380,1410] (1410,1440] (1440,1470]
[50] (1470,1500] (1500,1530] (1530,1560] (1560,1590] (1590,1620] (1620,1650] (1650,1680]
[57] (1680,1710] (1710,1740] (1740,1770] (1770,1800] (1800,1830] (1830,1860] (1860,1890]
[64] (1890,1920] (1920,1950] (1950,1980] <NA>       
66 Levels: (0,30] (30,60] (60,90] (90,120] (120,150] (150,180] (180,210] ... (1950,1980]
```

Comment: thanks! everything is easy in R if you know how hahaha

Comment: @Kay It is `base R`, all have a deep secret :)